# zip.exe found in C:\Windows

Tags: windows-7, zip

I was looking at my `C:\Windows` folder on Windows 7 today and noticed a really old version of `zip.exe`

```
Copyright (C) 1990-1999 Info-ZIP
Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 2.3 (November 29th 1999). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
```

Is this a hidden gem of Windows or did this get into the folder some other way? I have always wanted a command line way to zip/unzip from a stock Windows install.

Comment: I have a bunch of zipfldr.dll in my Windows 7 install. But no zip.exe

Comment: @SmetadAnarkist `zipfldr.dll` is in **System32**. Please read carefully the question.

Comment: I think you could make a definite argument that this isn't a SU-type question. Then again, you could do the opposite, too. In any case, that's kinda cool. Apparently this version has bugs: http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#corruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows NT has never included such file. Looks like it was installed by some third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a fresh copy of windows 7 pro SP1 and there is no zip.exe in C:\Windows. Maybe you are just really lucky!

Answer (score 0):

Looking up [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/) shows a user-group that have created 'free, portable, high-quality versions of the Zip and UnZip compressor-archiver utilities that are compatible with the DOS-based PKZIP'.

Apparently their versions have been used in quite a number of places.

> Some of the more interesting ones (well, historically speaking)
>   include the use of UnZip code in the unzip.dll distributed with IBM's
>   OS/2 Warp BonusPak and WebExplorer, as part of the reinstallation code
>   for the IBM Aptivas preloaded with OS/2 Warp, and as part of IBM's
>   Infoprint product. Sun used Info-ZIP's self-extractor to distribute
>   the NT version of their HotJava browser, Novell uses UnZip for NetWare
>   6 installation, and SAP includes it in Business One. Various Windows
>   products such as WinZip and the DynaZIP DLLs incorporate Info-ZIP
>   code, too. And let us not forget Pretty Good Privacy (PGP), an
>   excellent encryption program that uses Info-ZIP code as a first step
>   in encrypting files. Info-ZIP's primary compression engine has also
>   been spun off into the free zlib compression library, used in
>   Netscape/Mozilla/Firefox, the Linux kernel, Windows, Java, virtually
>   all PNG-supporting software, and countless other products.

Maybe something in that list points to software you may have installed that included the `zip.exe` in your windows folder.